# Xero WebHook Force.com Site

Tags: api, restresource, xero

I am trying to get Xero to send a WebHook to Salesforce so we can capture updates to Contacts and Invoices.

I created an Unauthenticated RESTful web-service by exposing the RestResource annotated Apex Class to the Force.com Site Guest User.

But I am receiving back errors! Xero will not authorise an Endpoint unless it replies with an empty body and without cookies, however, Salesforce always returns back the BrowserId Cookie and I cannot work out how to remove this!

Does anyone have any ideas how to remove this? Or am I trying to find air in space?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing myself and unfortunately I can't work out a way to remove the cookie either I've tried numerous things by overriding the RestResponse but not having much luck...

Will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Yeah I tried that also... the ONLY way I have been able to work out what is going on here is to create a small piece of "middleware" using Node.js on the Heroku platform... but I am absolutely lost with querying the data from Xero from the Node.js app #Newbie

Comment: Yea that's my only alternative solution as well, set up a custom endpoint on Heroku or similar to receive the message from Xero. From there, you can either:


1. Query Xero from the custom app to retrieve the data and then push that into Salesforce using the standard SOAP/REST API; OR
2. The custom app could just pass the Xero message straight to your Salesforce endpoint, and then Salesforce queries Xero for the data it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an update from Xero today saying they had deployed a change and it will accept the BrowserId Cookie that is returned by Salesforce so you should be good to go now :)

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: well I am getting the ITR... but I am having some issues with the HMAC encryption... it doesn't seem to want to work for me -_- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222446/xero-webhook-validation

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the update. I'll implement this and happy to share my code.